# Global temporary table behaviour in Schduler jobs in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks

I have a stage table in data migration which has huge data and we have divided the data into several chunks and submitted them at once to oracle scheduler job for parallel process which creates individual jobs/process on server. My Question is can i convert the stage table into a Global temporary table and expect each job to have data during execution.

Comment: Are you asking if the Global Temporary Table will preserve rows across sessions or if parallel processing happens in the same session?

Comment: *"can i convert the stage table into a Global temporary table and expect each job to have data during execution."* Yes. No. Maybe. It depends how you populate the GTT. So what benefits do you expect to derive from converting your existing table into a GTT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i convert the stage table into a Global temporary table ...

Yes, you can.

---

> ... and expect each job to have data during execution

Yes, each process will see only its own data, while all of them sharing the same global temporary table definition.